# Why am I getting an out of bounds exception error?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am currently working on a project and I have finally finished writing my code but for some reason I am getting a lot of errors and I am not sure where they are. I know it is frowned upon for posting the whole code here, I am working on Java and it is very difficult for me to find errors on Java. My project partner has never been helpful. I am the only one carrying the burden.

Here is my code

```
 public class Main {

    public static int Statement_Number = 1;
    public static String Current_Statement;
    public static int i = 0; //Index for Script
    public static int j = 0; //Index for Statements
    public static String Missing_Word; 
    public static ArrayList<String> Letters_of_the_missing_word = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static char WhiteSpace = ' '; 
    public static String Movie_Script; 
    public static char Missing_Word_Characters[] = new char[20]; 


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int count = 0; 
        int length = 0; //Length to compute LPS 
        char Underscore = '_'; 

        ArrayList<String> Statements_List = new ArrayList<String>();



        boolean word_missing = false; 
        BufferedReader Statements = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hasan\\Desktop\\Programming\\Java Programs\\Analysis of Algorithms Project\\term_project\\statements.txt"));
        BufferedReader Script = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hasan\\Desktop\\Programming\\Java Programs\\Analysis of Algorithms Project\\term_project\\the_truman_show_script.txt"));
        Movie_Script = Script.readLine();  
        int Script_Length = Movie_Script.length(); 
        //System.out.println(Script_Length);  //81,902



        //System.out.println(Movie_Script); 

        while((Current_Statement = Statements.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Statements_List.add(Current_Statement);
            int Current_Statement_length = Current_Statement.length(); 

            for(Statement_Number = 0; Statement_Number < 6; Statement_Number++)
            {
                //System.out.println(Statements_List.get(i));
                Current_Statement = Statements_List.get(Statement_Number); 
                System.out.println(Statement_Number + ". " + Current_Statement);
                KMPSearch(Current_Statement, Movie_Script); 
            }
        }


}

    static void KMPSearch(String Current_Statement, String Movie_Script)
    {
        int Current_Statement_Length = Current_Statement.length(); 
        int Movie_Script_Length = Movie_Script.length(); 
        int lps[] = new int[Current_Statement_Length];
        int j = 0; //Index for Current_Statement
        char Underscore = '_';

        Calculating_LPS_Array(Current_Statement, Current_Statement_Length, lps);

        int i = 0; 
        while(i < Movie_Script_Length)
        {
            if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) == Movie_Script.charAt(i))
            {
                i++; 
                j++; 
            }
            else if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) != Movie_Script.charAt(i) && Current_Statement.charAt(j) == Underscore)
            {
                //Replace the underscores with the word
                Word_Getter(); 
                String New_Statement = Current_Statement.replaceAll("___", Missing_Word); 
                System.out.println(New_Statement);
                System.out.println(""); 
            }
            else if(i < Movie_Script_Length && Current_Statement.charAt(j) != Movie_Script.charAt(i))
            {
                if(j != 0)
                {
                    j = lps[j - 1]; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    i = i + 1; 
                }
            }
        }

        if(i == Movie_Script_Length)
        {
            System.out.println("STATEMENT NOT FOUND"); 
        }
    }

    static void Calculating_LPS_Array(String Current_Statement, int Current_Statement_Length, int lps[])
    {
        int len = 0; 
        int i = 1; 
        lps[0] = 0; 
        while(i < Current_Statement_Length)
        {
            if(Current_Statement.charAt(i) == Current_Statement.charAt(len))
            {
                len++; 
                lps[i] = len; 
                i++; 
            }
        else    //Current_Statement.charAt(i) != Current_Statement.charAt(len)
            {
                if(len != 0)
                {
                    len = lps[len - 1]; 
                }
                else
                {
                    lps[i] = len; 
                    i++; 
                }

            }
        }
    }

    static void Word_Getter()
    {
        if(Movie_Script.charAt(j) != WhiteSpace)
        {
            Movie_Script.getChars(j, WhiteSpace, Missing_Word_Characters, 0);
            j++; 
            Missing_Word = new String(Missing_Word_Characters); 
        }

    }

}
```

Here are the errors that I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   offset 0, count 32, length 20     at
>   java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsOffCount(String.java:3304)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:855)  at
>   Main.Word_Getter(Main.java:142)   at Main.KMPSearch(Main.java:85)     at
>   Main.main(Main.java:57)

Your help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You're trying to put 32 characters into a character array with size 20. Could you try to make the `Missing_Word_Characters` array of size 32? So `public static char Missing_Word_Characters[] = new char[32];`

Comment: Hey. I did that. It worked but there is one annoying problem. My output isn't what it's supposed to be. Here's what I am getting looks up into the sky but there is no E TRUMAN SHOW A Screen Play Byyy in sight The word is replaced but with the wrong word (multiple words in fact). The answer is supposed to be "plane". 

It is apparently replacing from the first character from the second txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the size of your Array :

```
public static char Missing_Word_Characters[] = new char[32];
```

Comment: Hey. I did that. It worked but there is one annoying problem. My output isn't what it's supposed to be.
Here's what I am getting 
looks up into the sky but there is no E TRUMAN SHOW A Screen Play Byyy in sight

The word is replaced but with the wrong word (multiple words in fact). The answer is supposed to be "plane".

It is apparently replacing from the first character from the second txt file.